# angular2 form builder with input type="radio"

Tags: forms, angular

I would we very grateful for an example of using form builder with

```
<input type="radio">
```

I'm looking for solution that doesn't use custom event handling but the one with proper use of ng-model and ng-control.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879497/angular2-radio-button-binding  .. it seems that it's not implemented yet 

https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2/src/core/forms/directives

Comment: i don't think there is any proper tutorial is there using ngModel and ngControl but yes i have solution without using these to get the value of radio button selected if you want ill post it as answer ?