# EXCEPTION: No provider for Angular 2 custom form input

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am trying to implements

> ControlValueAccessor

For a custom Angular 2 form input

I am getting the EXCEPTION

> EXCEPTION: No provider for MyDatePicker! (MyDatePickerValueAccessor -> MyDatePicker)

I uploaded the code in to  Plunker

[**Plunker** Custom Control 
**Event Binding**  *Working*](http://plnkr.co/edit/2mxnFd?p=preview)

[**Plunker** Custom Control 
**Value Accessor** *Not Working*](http://plnkr.co/edit/kacoC9?p=preview)

and also here my  ControlValueAccessor implementation

```
    import {MyDatePicker} from './MyDatePicker';
    import { Directive, Provider, forwardRef , } from 'angular2/core';
    import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from 'angular2/common';
    import {CONST_EXPR} from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';

    const CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR = CONST_EXPR(new Provider(
        NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, { useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyDatePickerValueAccessor), multi: false }));

    @Directive({
        selector: 'my-date-picker',
        host: { '(dateChanged)': 'onChange($event)' },
        providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
    })
    export class MyDatePickerValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
        onChange = (_) => { };
        onTouched = () => { };

        constructor(private host: MyDatePicker) { }

        writeValue(value: any): void {
            this.host.selDate = value;
        }

        registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
        registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
    }
```

Here some of the links from my research:

- [typescript - Angular 2 custom form input - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948961/angular-2-custom-form-input)
- [forms - Angular2 - Radio Button Binding - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879497/angular2-radio-button-binding)
- [ControlValueAccessor - ts](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html)
- [Forms - ts](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)
- [Implementing Angular2 forms – Beyond basics (part 2) | Restlet - We Know About APIs](http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/)
- [ng2-ckeditor/CKEditor.d.ts at 6699185310a5d50776b541ae7a2ae5cb55e4394a · chymz/ng2-ckeditor](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/blob/6699185310a5d50776b541ae7a2ae5cb55e4394a/CKEditor.d.ts)
- [restlet-sample-angular2-forms/company.details.ts at master · restlet/restlet-sample-angular2-forms](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-sample-angular2-forms/blob/master/app/components/company.details.ts)
- [angular/control_value_accessor.ts at 2.0.0-beta.9 · angular/angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.9/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/control_value_accessor.ts#L34-L34)

Comment: `multi: true`, then you have another issue you can track.

Comment: thanks , this one helps , looks like the return value is an object from the MyDatePicker

Comment: remove `,` from imports `angular2/core`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from 
❤️[@mnv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949077/4879683)❤️
 and 
❤️[@eric-martinez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948989/exception-no-provider-for-angular-2-custom-form-input?noredirect=1#comment59555155_35948989)❤️

I did find an answer

---

## MyDatePicker.ts

---

1. Add

   ```
   setValue(value) {
       this.selectionDayTxt = value;
       if(this.selectionDayTxt !== '') {
         let fmt = this.options.dateFormat !== undefined ? 
                   this.options.dateFormat : this.dateFormat;
         let dpos = fmt.indexOf('dd');
         let mpos = fmt.indexOf('mm');
         let ypos = fmt.indexOf('yyyy');
         this.selectedDate = {day: parseInt(this.selectionDayTxt
                               .substring(dpos, dpos + 2)),
             month: parseInt(
               this.selectionDayTxt.substring(mpos, mpos + 2)),
             year: parseInt(
               this.selectionDayTxt.substring(ypos, ypos + 4))};
       }
       if(this.selectionDayTxt !== '') {
           this.selectionDayTxtForServer = 
               this.formatDateForServer(this.selectedDate);
       }
   }
   ```

2.From

```
    //ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    //  this.selectionDayTxt = changes['selDate'].currentValue;
    //  if(this.selectionDayTxt !== '') {
    //      let fmt = this.options.dateFormat !== undefined ? 
    //                  this.options.dateFormat : this.dateFormat;
    //      let dpos = fmt.indexOf('dd');
    //      let mpos = fmt.indexOf('mm');
    //      let ypos = fmt.indexOf('yyyy');
    //      this.selectedDate = {day: parseInt(this.selectionDayTxt
    //                  .substring(dpos, dpos + 2)),
    //      month: parseInt(this.selectionDayTxt.substring(mpos, mpos + 2)),
    //      year: parseInt(this.selectionDayTxt.substring(ypos, ypos + 4))};
    //  }
    //}
```

3.to

```
    ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
        this.setValue(changes['selDate'].currentValue);
    }
```

## MyDatePickerValueAccessor.ts

---

1. from

   ```
   //const CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR = CONST_EXPR(
   //new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, { useExisting: forwardRef(() => 
   //                          MyDatePickerValueAccessor), multi: false }));
   ```
2. to

   ```
   const CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR = CONST_EXPR(
   new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, { useExisting: forwardRef(() => 
                               MyDatePickerValueAccessor), multi: true }));
   ```
3. from

   ```
   //providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR , ]
   ```
4. to

   ```
   providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR , MyDatePicker,ElementRef]
   ```
5. from

   ```
   //host: { '(dateChanged)': 'onChange($event)' }
   ```
6. to

   ```
   host: { '(dateChanged)': 'onChange($event.formattedForServer)' }
   ```
7. from

   ```
   //writeValue(value: any): void {
       //this.host.selDate = value;
   //}
   ```
8. to

   ```
   writeValue(value: any): void {
       this.host.setValue(value);
   }
   ```

---

here is the full example

- http://plnkr.co/edit/csFaER?p=preview

and here the original mydatepicker

- [Github : Angular2 date picker - Angular2 reusable UI component](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker)

Answer (score 3):

Try to write

```
providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR, MyDatePicker]
```

Comment: it give EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of NgControlName!.

Comment: But there are another error now: `Error during instantiation of t!.`

Comment: thanks , this one helps ,  providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR , MyDatePicker,ElementRef] ,

Comment: Error during instantiation is from the  MyDatePicke it self