# Angular2- Object as Radio Input Value

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, forms

Is it possible to bind a JSON object to a radio input in Angular2?

I have a JSON object named `object` and I tried

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedObject" [ngValue]="object">
```

but it gives `ngValue is not a known property of input` error. I also tried

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedObject" value="{{object}}">
```

But then `selectedObject` becomes `[object Object]`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879497/angular2-radio-button-binding This might help

Comment: @Kapein Values are just strings in this example, I want to bind JSON objects to the value.

Comment: Any luck finding an answer here? I, too, am stuck with this one...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44141824/463059), we have an answer:
Use `[value]`

```
<label *ngFor="let item of items">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="options" [value]="item">
    {{item}}
</label>
```

Thanks to [Colleen Purcell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7157507/colleen-purcell)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code in Angular 1, without testing converted to angular 2 for you

```
<span *ngFor="let List in object.Lists">
    <input type="radio" name="{{List.ID}}" value="{{List.Value}}">
</span>
```

Comment: I don't want the value to be `object.attribute`, I want it to be the `object` itself.

Comment: and what do you think about using indexes and then OnChange(index), then you look up which index in the array you want and copy it?

Not sure if that works with  [(ngModel)], not an Angular 2 expert

Comment: If I use `onChange`, the model is updated when I select the button but it doesn't be selected when the model is changed externally (not two way binding).