# Angular 2 - How to read touched of radio button with ngModel

Tags: forms, angular, radio-button

I'm wrapping my head around forms and ngModel currently. So far everything works great except for the radio buttons.
They are loaded and all but I can't manage to read the touched state.
I guess it is because they are generated within a for loop and therefore can't be referenced

```
<fieldset [ngClass]="{'has-error': someReference.touched 
                                   && someReference.invalid}">
    <legend>Salutation</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="salutation_m">
            <input id="salutation_m" name="salutation" type="radio" 
                   [ngModel]="registration.salutation" #someReference="ngModel">
            <span>Mister</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

So far it looks like the reference can't be read. I don't get any errors but even when the element is touched and invalid the class is not set.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

Changed #someReference to #someReference="ngModel" which solves the problem for predefined radio buttons but not for generated ones inside of a for loop.

I'm guessing in the case of a for loop there is a problem with the scope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879497/angular2-radio-button-binding

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but it isn't really helpful. Like I said, the radios are loaded and working except of the class not being set.
So far I figured, that I forgot to add ngModel after someReference like `#someReference="ngModel"` which works for predefined radio buttons, but not for radio buttons generated inside a for loop. Guess that is a different problem because of the scopes...