# How to pass input value as parameter to router in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I believe what I'm trying to do is trivial, but I've tried many different things and can't figure it out.

I have two components, `SearchComponent` and `DetailsComponent` that displays search results.

A route module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: SearchComponent},
{ path: 'armory/:name', component: DetailsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and an input in `search.component.html`

```
<form class="form-inline container-fluid">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Character name..." class="form-control">
  <button (click)="onSearch( ... <!--name should be here-->)" class="btn">
    <span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
</form>
```

and then in `search.component.ts`:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private router: Router) {
}

onSearch(name: string) {
   this.router.navigate(['/armory', name])
}
}
```

How do I get the `name` input's value and pass it as a parameter to `onSearch()`?

Comment: What type of form are you using ? Model driven or template driven ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the value of **name** you can simply assign a reference to the input field like this `#name`. Here's what you need to do:

> search.component.html

```
 <form class="form-inline container-fluid">
  <input type="text" id="name" #name  placeholder="Character name..." 
  class="form-control">
  <button (click)="onSearch(name.value)" class="btn">
   <span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
  </form>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this for radio button group? https://pastebin.com/d3bhhD1p here on line 12 instead of `'Feronis' ` in `onSearch()`

Comment: @Asalas77 Here's a link that will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879497/angular2-radio-button-binding