# Angular: How to get data from radio button group and pass it as a parameter to a method?

Tags: javascript, angular, input, parameters

I have a two-choice radio group that I want to get a selected value of and pass it as one of the parameters to navigate to. In my earlier semi-related question someone suggested this solution: [Angular2 - Radio Button Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879497/angular2-radio-button-binding) but I've been trying and failing to use it:

**search.component.html:**

```
 <form autocomplete="on" class="form-inline">
<input style="border-color: white; max-width: 300px" name="name" autofocus type="text" #name placeholder="Name..."
       class="form-control">
<div class=" btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn  btn-toggle active">
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="realm" name="realm" [ng-value]="'Feronis'" autocomplete="off" checked> Feronis
  </label>
  <label class="btn  btn-toggle">
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="realm" name="realm" [ng-value]="'Angrathar'" autocomplete="off"> Angrathar
  </label>
</div>
<button (click)="onSearch(name.value,realm)" class="btn btn-search">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
```

I also tried with `ngValue` and `value`.

**search.component.ts:**

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

     realm: string;

onSearch(nameIn: string, realmIn: string) {
    console.log(this.realm); // undefined
    let nameCase = nameIn.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
                      nameIn.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    let realmCase = realmIn.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + // realmIn also undefined
                      realmIn.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    this.router.navigate(['/character', realmCase, nameCase])
}}
```

> Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

I also have imports for 
`import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";` in `app.module.ts` and `search.component.ts`

Comment: ng-value is not a valid property on input element, you have to instead use value property in either [value]="expressnion" or value="actual-value" way.

Comment: @varunsingh I'll copy my other comment: I get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined` when I do `onSearch(name.value,realm)` with `value="Feronis"`. The console.log is also undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/9YOV50bV1E9F9tH3Uw8a

It seems everything is fine except the fact that you want first radio button to be pre-selected.

You are doing pre-selection using checked property. Now since you are using `[ngModel]="realm"`, ngModel sets initial value. In your case initial value of realm  is undefined, none of the radion button gets pre-selected.

Set some value in realm in your class, to get pre-selected radio button as shown in plunker above.

Comment: Ok I really don't understand it now, I copied everything from you plunker into a new component in my project and it stopped working... I only get the default value

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer even though it didn't work in my project. It works on plunker so I guess the issue is in something else. I ended up ditching the radio buttons and replaced them with a single button that toggles between two values.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `value` instead of `[ng-value]`

for example

```
value="Feronis"
```

Because as you specify `[ng-value]="'Feronis'"` here you trying attribute binding with static string 
which is equal to simply assign of value using value attribute like this

```
value="Feronis"
```

> Solution for : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

No need to send value of radio selected as param just fetch the value using `this.realm` like this

```
console.log(nameIn, this.realm);
```

and your `search` function looks like

```
(click)="onSearch(name.value)"
```

> Working code

```
<form autocomplete="on" class="form-inline">
    <input style="border-color: white; max-width: 300px" name="name" autofocus type="text" #name placeholder="Name..." class="form-control">
    <div class=" btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn  btn-toggle active">
        <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="realm" name="realm" value="Feronis" autocomplete="off" checked> Feronis
      </label>
        <label class="btn  btn-toggle">
        <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="realm" name="realm" value="Angrathar" autocomplete="off"> Angrathar
      </label>
    </div>
    <button (click)="onSearch(name.value)" class="btn btn-search">
      <span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
</form>

onSearch(nameIn: string) {
    console.log(nameIn, this.realm);
 }
```

Comment: I get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined` when I do `onSearch(name.value,realm)` with `value="Feronis"`. The console.log is also undefined

Comment: Unfortunately no change, the console log of 
    `console.log('name: '+nameIn + ', realm: '+this.realm);` is still `name: test, realm: undefined`

Comment: Please check my code above
just a tip : never use `+` in console instead use `,`

Comment: The code you posted is just like what I had when I made my previous comment. Just to test I did the same to `name` using ngModel and `this.name` and `onSearch()` with no params and this part works: `nameVariable:  hgfhgf , realm:  undefined`

Comment: i think something else causing issue on your end. on my end everything is working fine :)

Comment: Well I'm vary new to Angular so perhaps I'm missing something essential that you wouldn't even think of. Would you take a look at full code? https://github.com/adamzimnyy/SunwellFront/tree/master/src/app/search