# Don't know why two way binding isn't working

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have an Ionic/Angular app where I have a group of radio buttons. I'm binding them to a property in the control, but for some reason I'm not seeing the value of the selected item.

Here is the html:

```
<ion-list radio-group>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Personal</ion-label>
        <ion-radio
        ngDefaultControl 
        checked="true" 
        value="personal"
        name="personal"
        [(ngModel)]="shared.card_type" ></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Business</ion-label>
      <ion-radio 
      ngDefaultControl
      checked="false" 
      value="business"
      name="business"
      [(ngModel)]="shared.card_type" ></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I have a 'shared' object declared:   shared:IShared;
and initialized in the constructor:  this.shared = {};

All the other properties, which are not radio buttons, are binding ok.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: have you checked whether its contain value or not,did you get any errors,  Can you post the  code where you are binding in shared object the card_type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Radio Button Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879497/angular2-radio-button-binding)

Comment: If your question isn't answered in the linked question, please add more code. Your `ts` file of this html page and the `IShared` object