# Angular2 - How can I know which radio button is selected in Angular2 application

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, binding

I  have the  next radio buttons in my html:

```
<div class="col-lg-4" id="radioButtons"> 
    <form action="">
        <fieldset id="capacity">
            <legend>capacity</legend>
            <label for="input-ao"><input size=25 id="input-ao" type="radio" name="capacity" [value]="0-30" checked="checked" />0-30</label>
            <label for="input-lo"><input id="input-lo" type="radio" name="capacity" [value]="30-60"/>30-60</label>
            <label for="input-lo"><input id="input-lo" type="radio" name="capacity" [value]="60-100"/>60-100</label>
            <label for="input-lo"><input id="input-lo" type="radio" name="capacity" [value]="100"/>100+</label>
            <br>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="computerFieldset">
            <legend>computer</legend>
            <label for="input-ao"><input size=25 id="input-ao" type="radio" name="comp" value="yes" checked="checked" />yes</label>
            <label for="input-lo"><input id="input-lo" type="radio" name="comp" value="no"/>no</label>
            <br>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to know which radio button is selected, also I want to know will it cause a problem that I have a default `checked="checked"`?  Thank you.

Comment: You should not have 2 radio buttons with the same id - in your HTML structure. It will  mess up the functionality, IMO.

Comment: Have a look at the link :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879497/angular2-radio-button-binding

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `[(ngModel)]="YourVariableFromTsCodeBehindFile"` to each radio button of your radio group.

It should look like,

```
<div class="col-lg-4" id="radioButtons"> 
  <form action="">
    <fieldset id="capacity">
      <legend>capacity</legend>
      <label for="input-ao"><input [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioBtnFrom1stGroup" size=25 type="radio" name="capacity" value="0-30" checked="checked" />0-30</label>
      <label for="input-lo"><input [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioBtnFrom1stGroup" type="radio" name="capacity"  value="30-60"/>30-60</label>
      <label for="input-lo"><input [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioBtnFrom1stGroup" type="radio" name="capacity"  value="60-100"/>60-100</label>
      <label for="input-lo"><input [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioBtnFrom1stGroup" type="radio" name="capacity"  value="100"/>100+</label>
      <br>
      {{selectedRed}}
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="computerFieldset">
      <legend>computer</legend>
      <label for="input-ao"><input size=25 [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioBtnFrom2ndGroup" type="radio" name="comp" value="yes" checked="checked" />yes</label>
      <label for="input-lo"><input [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioBtnFrom2ndGroup" type="radio" name="comp" value="no"/>no</label>

      <br>
    {{blue.id}}   
    </fieldset>  
  </form>
</div>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-radio-button-demo-ksrxbc?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use a changeHandler method, for example - as it is shown in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wo9nfK2fEyw

Example:

```
<label for="input-ao"><input size=25 id="input-ao" type="radio" name="capacity" [value]="0-30" checked="checked" (change)="radioChangeHandler($event)" />0-30</label>

radioChangeHandler(event: any){
    this.selectedRadioButton = event.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function called radioChanged()
And within this function you can console the value of the selected radio input

radioChange(event: any){console.log(event.target.value)}

Its just an idea. Because i have no laptop right now.. 
If you do not understand the concept let me know i will edit the answer